# Grant execute permission to an SQL Server user to run a specific job only

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, jobs

I have the request to create an SQL Server Agent Job that can be run by a specific SQL User.

How can this be done without giving the user execute permission to `sp_start_job` stored procedure meaning that he could run all the other prohibited jobs too?

Comment: By creating a procedure using `EXECUTE AS OWNER` that starts only that job, and granting the user permission on that. (If for whatever reason `EXECUTE AS OWNER` is seen as too risky or you have cross-database issues, read [this](http://sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) for more details on how to do things "neatly" with certificates.)

Comment: Sadly, the execute as owner won't work due to security issues. Thank you for the link, i will read it.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on your statement *"due to security issues"*? What issues in particular?

Comment: Use certificates as Jeroen mentioned. It's the best way but also the most complex one.

Answer (score 5):

> How can this be done without giving the user execute permission to sp_start_job stored procedure meaning that he could run all the other prohibited jobs too?

Usually, a user assigned to `SQLAgentUserRole` (database role in `msdb`) can only have access to the SQL Job that the user as owner,

**In your case, you can apply simple steps as follows**

Following steps creates a Job that would be executable by a `login` and same `login` could NOT be able to run other jobs available in SQL Agent:

1. While creating Job (have a look at sample reference), include the desired `login` name as Job owner by including it in parameter `@owner_login_name`
2. Ensure the `Login` mapped as Job owner (in step 1) is not part of `Sysadmin` fixed server role and `SQLAgentOperatorRole` msdb database role, but only part of `SQLAgentUserRole` role, you can do this with following script (replace the word **Loginname** with your own)

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE SYSADMIN DROP MEMBER LoginName;

USE MSDB;

CREATE USER LoginName FOR LOGIN LoginName;

ALTER ROLE SQLAGENTUSERROLE ADD MEMBER LoginName;

ALTER ROLE SQLAgentOperatorRole drop MEMBER LoginName;
```

---

**Job Creation Sample reference**

The script creates a Job and step, step execute T-SQL command via `sqlcmd`, the user who runs this job doesn't required permission on particular object in the database.

You need to change `@command` parameter before running following script that creates the job. Or you can change it later (after job creation) via *SSMS - SQL Agent -> Job properties*

*Note: SQL Agent Service must run by windows/domain user account, and the service account user required permissions on the object (Procedure)*

```
USE [msdb]
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'Cmd Test With Service Account', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'sa', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [Test]    Script Date: 8/27/2019 5:30:58 PM ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Cmd Test With Service Account', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'CmdExec', 
        @command=N'"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -S Localhost,1534 -Q "exec YourDatabase.dbo.YourProcedure"', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:
GO
```

---

Comment: How would this stop a users starting other jobs?

Comment: @Larnu, sorry, i got the question wrongly, and miss to cover full answer. However, edited my answer which compliance to the question now. Thanks for notifying!

Comment: That doesn't stop the user starting **other** jobs.

Comment: @Larnu, Could you pls explain how `login`/`user` can run the job without being part of `sysadmin` or `SQLAgentOperatorRole`. also, not the owner of Job while being member of `SQLAgentUserRole`

Comment: The OP specifically stats that the don't want the user to be able to run other jobs. it's not *my* requirement, it's the OP's; but this doesn't meet that.

Comment: @Larnu, agree on the requirement, and i believe, edited post of course meets the OP's requirement as it states _a user need to be able to run particular SQL Agent job without be able to have access to all other jobs_, if not, let OP describe it with edit.

Comment: For this to work, the SQL Agent Job has to be assigned/owned by the SQL User needing to execute the job, and the user has to be part of the SQLAgentUserRole. More info available here: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent-fixed-database-roles?view=sql-server-2017#sqlagentuserrole-permissions). By definition of the role, the user will not be able to execute other SQL Server Agent Jobs of which it is not the owner.