# SQL Server Admin permission on specific job

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need to run a job as `SQLAgentReaderRole` and it is working fine (as the job contains Proxy, etc.). BUT I need also to modify somehow the role to specific user and specific job.

For example:
I have 3 different jobs (`Job1,Job2,Job3`) and all of can be seen in Jobs drop-down in SSMS.
Also I need to run only `Job2` without seeing the `Job1` and `Job3`. Is it possible to do it somehow (of course the Filter is not an option)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a stored procedure that runs the job. You can use `with execute as owner` to run the stored procedure as the database owner. That way, the user doesn't need permissons on sp_start_job.

```
create procedure dbo.DoYourJob
with execute as owner
as
exec sp_start_job @job_name = 'YourJob'
```

Grant execute rights on `DoYourJob` to allow specific users to start the job.

this might be useful as well
[Grant execute permission to an SQL Server user to run a specific job only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623638/grant-execute-permission-to-an-sql-server-user-to-run-a-specific-job-only)

Comment: Is there anyway to do it in SSMS GUI, instead of using stored procedure? I have a lots of parameters and it will be better for users to run the job through the GUI.

Comment: [like this?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/start-a-job?view=sql-server-ver15#SSMS)

Comment: "OWNER
Specifies the statements inside the module executes in the context of the current owner of the module. If the module does not have a specified owner, the owner of the schema of the module is used" - which is often the owner of the DB but not always.

Comment: @MitchWheat do i have to correct anything in my answer?

Comment: @CarloPrato is it possible to add more than 1 owner to a JOB?

Comment: @bulprosbibg i think [like this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124331/sql-server-sql-agent-allow-a-group-to-own-a-job)

Comment: @CarloPrato yes but they speak for stored procedure again. I need to run the job via SSMS SQL Server Agent, not as Query using stored procedure